# menu based programme withwhile and switch statements?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am a beginner and i am trying to learn on my own. I wrote a switch case statement on my own which is menu based one.all the programme is ok but when the menu reappears the menu is not appearing properly!

code is

```
int main()
{
    char menu
    int i,num,fact=1,d;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("enter 'a' to find out factorial of a number\n");
        printf("enter 'b' to find out that number is prime or not\n");
        printf("enter 'c' to find out that number is odd or even\n");
        printf("enter 'd' to exit");
        scanf("%c",&menu);

        switch(menu)
        {
        case 'a':
            printf("please enter the number ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            for(i=1; i<=num; i++)
                fact=fact*i;
            printf("factorial is %d\n",fact);
            break;

        case'b':
            printf("enter the number");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            for(i=2; i<=num-1; i++)
            {
                if(num%i==0)
                {
                    printf("not a prime number\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(i==num)
            {
                printf("prime number\n");
                break;
            }
            break;

        case'c':
            printf("enter the number\n");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            d=num%2;
            if(d=0)
                printf("its a even number\n");
            else
                printf("its a odd one\n");
            break;

        case'd':
            exit(0);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please learn to indent your code, it's a good practice and it's really better to the reusability and maintainability of your code.

Comment: You need to improve your code `if(d=0)` to `if(d==0)` in the even-number section,else it'll be always true!

Comment: change `scanf("%c",&menu);` to `scanf(" %c",&menu);` for remaining newline.

Comment: Why menu is not appearing properly,what kind of peculiarity are you facing?

Comment: You should think about a "default" statement in your switch, to catch all other inputs and say something like "KeyError" etc. It's a good use to always catch all case of a switch. `default: printf("KeyError : '%c'", menu)`

Comment: @Alexander tobias , thank you for your help. but after the modification i cant input for second time in the menu. pls see

Comment: @user2132030-Kindly accept the answer if your problem has been resolved!

Comment: my problem not yet resolved , i cant input choice second time in pls see

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   int ok=1;
    while(1)
    {
        if(ok==1)
        {
        printf("enter 'a' to find out factorial of a number\n");
        printf("enter 'b' to find out that number is prime or not\n");
        printf("enter 'c' to find out that number is odd or even\n");
        printf("enter 'd' to exit\n");
        scanf("%c",&menu);
        fflush(stdin);
        }
        ok=1;

        switch(menu)
        {
        case 'a':
            printf("please enter the number ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            for(i=1; i<=num; i++)
                fact=fact*i;
            printf("factorial is %d\n",fact);
            break;
        ......
        ......
        default: ok=0;break;

        }
    }
```

The menu works fine on my system with this modification.

Also check out shekhar suman's answer to remove obvious bugs.